# Изменение кастомного макета для Spinner'a после его создания

Tags: android, ui, android-spinner

Можно ли как-нибудь изменить кастомный макет для `Spinner`'a после его создания?
Например, у меня есть `Spinner`, макет которого состоит из `TextView` и `ImageView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_sorting"
    ... />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_downward"
    ... />
```

наполнение его выглядит так:

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_sorting);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_row, R.id.tv_sorting, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sorting_array));
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

и в итоге Spinner выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне хотелось бы изменить каждую вторую `ImageView` в этом `Spinnere`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: пишите кастомный адаптер и делайте там что хотите с каждым айтемом аналогично как это делается для списков ListView

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за совет, создала кастомный адаптер, получилось сделать то, что было нужно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создала кастомный адаптер для Spinner-a:

```
public class SortingSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private String[] data;

    public SortingSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] data) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, data);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return createView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return createView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View createView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sorting);
            holder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        return convertView;
    }

    private void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int pos) {
        holder.textView.setText(data[pos]);
        if (pos % 2 == 0) {
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_downward));
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_upward));
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

В итоге получила именно то, что хотела:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]